# After Login Open specific Navigationtab

Tags: ms-access, vba

In my MS-Access Database I Got a LoginForm, which checks If a User has Access to a specific form or Not.
My main, called "NavigationsFormular" has 4 Tabs
[image: Look of Navigationform]
A normal User can access the 1st tab called "Bautagesbericht".
A ControlingUser can access the 2nd, 3d, 4th tab, but not the 1st!

The Login Form is a pop-up at start, I dont want to change it to a tab too,that would be ugly and not optimal.
After the Login succeeded, it loads up the Navigationform.
For the normal user its no problem, but for the controlling part it always says " No access " because it tried to open a tab he's not permitted to.

Thats the Code btw:

```
    If Globals.UserAccess(Me.Name) = False Then
MsgBox " No access!"
DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
End If
```

Now my idea was, that the Login Form open the form, which the user got permissions to by following code:

```
If Globals.UserAccess("frm_Räumstellenerfassung") = False Then
DoCmd.BrowseTo ObjectType:=acBrowseToForm, _
ObjectName:="frm_Taetigkeitseingabe_Büro", _
PathToSubformControl:="Navigationsformular.NavigationsUnterformular>frm_Taetigkeitseingabe_Büro.NavigationsUnterformular"
DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
Else
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Navigationsformular"
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
    End If
End Sub
```

The Problem is that the Path is not right..
[image: Error]

> Hauptformular1 / MainFormular1   =   "NavigationsFormular"
>   Unterformular1 / SubForm1   =   "NavigationsUnterformular" (in German)
>   Formular1 = "frm_Taetigkeitseingabe_Büro"

Tried all combinations nothing helped.

**BTW:** A Button in my Naviagtion form with this Code is working. Apparently not when trying from an other form.

```
DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToForm, "frm_Taetigkeitseingabe_Büro","Navigationsformular.NavigationsUnterformular"
```

Comment: So, is the BTW statement an edit and you have resolved this issue? If not, have you tried that statement in your If Then block?

Comment: Yes I tried it. But it's not working if I am in an other Formular. Just working inside my main. (navigationsformular). I just wanted to show my affort :) ***edited that BTW statement to correct that misunderstanding

Comment: I REALLY, REALLY do not like Navigation form. Must understand that only one subform is available at a time (they are loaded when needed). So referencing another subform from a subform module will likely fail.

Comment: So is there any other choice than navigationsform I mean same look with highlighted stuff when mousover etc.? I just took it because its simple and looks nice when rightly edited. Or do you have any other idea doing with navigationsformu... Some "dirty" way.. Or real alternative. I really would appreciate some help or opinion!

Comment: Maybe the subform can pass a value to the parent form and code there does the BrowseTo. Just guessing. I use Tab control.

Answer (score 0):

ok I followed @June7 tipps. thanks for that. Here my solution:
Edited my form "frm_Räumstellenerfassung" ( Bautagesbericht) to

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
   DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
   If Globals.UserAccess("frm_Räumstellenerfassung") = False Then
   DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToForm, "frm_Taetigkeitseingabe_Büro",    "Navigationsformular.NavigationsUnterformular"
   End If
End Sub
```

So msg " No Access " is not popping up anymore and if the User has no rights to see this form, its browsing to the 2nd tab(Tätigkeitserfassung) without seeing any details of the 1st form.

My Login button just navigate to the navigationform

```
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Navigationsformular"
   DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
```